# Avoid geographic restrictions in the internet

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, geolocation

I am living in **UK** and I want to access some contents (*mostly streamings*) of websites that are only accesible from **Spain**.

I've first tried with some free **IP hiding** software, but the bandwidth they allow is very limited, so they're not useful. I think the proper way is to use a **VPN** but networking is not my forte...

In UK, I have a good broadband connection with dynamic IP address, and in Spain, in my family house, I have also a good broadband connection and some computers that may or may not be connected. This IP address is also dynamic.

So, my question is: what would be the best approach in a situation like this? Obviously I'd prefer a free solution, but I'm willing to pay if it's not too much...

---

What I'm doing now is:

1. First I have to tell my family when I need to access restricted content.
2. I use **TeamViewer** to access my family's computer and find the current IP.
3. Using their computer, I create a **VPN** using **Windows 7** (like [**this**](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-connection-in-windows-7/)).
4. Then I connect my computer in UK to that VPN.

The problem is that I have to repeat steps 1, 2 & 4 every time I want to watch something. Furthermore, with this approach:

- I need a computer switched on in Spain.
- Their broadband speed is affected.

---

*Note: I'm new here from Stack Overflow. I know this question doesn't fit in SO, but I'm not sure whether it fits here... if it doesn't, please excuse me.*

Comment: Isn't this what a proxy can be used for?

Comment: @Dave, I don't know, as I don't know much about networking...

Comment: This is the result of my Google search, check out the [2nd link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=use+proxy+to+mask+location&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) called "Hide My..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd see about renting a server in Spain, you can get a pretty small VPS and set up a VPN or just do ssh tunneling. It should have a static IP, so connecting will be easy, it should remain up and running always, and you could probably make more use of it, for example as a mail server. The costs are fairly small, as won't need a huge machine to do things like this.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, useful answer! but in fact it envolves buying the server, keeping it switched on every time, pay more for a static IP address and either I get another broadband connection or their broadband speed will be afected... so it's maybe the most expensive solution, isn't it?

Comment: No, if you rent a VPS, you can pay less than 10 euro a month, with unlimited bandwidth, and it will have at least one static IP. Have a look here, this was the first link that came up for me: http://www.spainvps.com/ it's in a data center so it should have good connectivity and stable power, and a machine like that should be able to handle a single VPN.. plus it's in spain so the IP geolocation should no longer be an issue.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand the answer correctly the first time! That's pretty good, thanks @Nick!

Comment: No problems, I hope you can enjoy your programs!